# Migrating data into Firebase from MySQL

Tags: mysql, firebase

I have an existing PHP/MySQL app which I am trying to migrate to AngularJS/Firebase, just as a way to learn these newer technologies.

The app has its own schema of tables in MySQL. One such table looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `dictionary` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `wordmeaning` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `wordlength` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My question is: how do I migrate this table structure, and the data in it, from MySQL to Firebase?

I have tried exporting the data into a JSON string via a query such as:

```
SELECT      CONCAT("[",
          GROUP_CONCAT(
               CONCAT("{id:'",id,"',"),
               CONCAT("word:'",word,"',"),
               CONCAT("wordmeaning:'",wordmeaning,"',"),
               CONCAT("wordlength:'",wordlength,"'}")
          )
     ,"]") 
AS json FROM dictionary;
```

This gives a valid JSON string such as:

```
[{id:'1',word:'cat',wordmeaning:'a mammal species',wordlength:'3'},
{id:'2',word:'catapult',wordmeaning:'throwing device',wordlength:'8'},
{id:'3',word:'cart',wordmeaning:'something to carry things in',wordlength:'4'}]
```

I saved this in a file and tried to import the file from Firebase, using the Import JSON button, to which I got:Error parsing JSON data. Please validate your input. (The JSON string is valid. I checked it at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Any ideas about what I could be doing wrong? I am assuming that Firebase can handle such structures and the data in them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. Change it to this to be valid:

```
[{"id":"1","word":"cat","wordmeaning":"a mammal species","wordlength":"3"},
{"id":"2","word":"catapult","wordmeaning":"throwing device","wordlength":"8"},
{"id":"3","word":"cart","wordmeaning":"something to carry things in","wordlength":"4"}]
```

So these are the changes:

1. use double-quotes instead of single-quotes
2. put (double) quotes around the keys, not just the values

You may want to consider not quoting the values of `id` and `wordlength`, since these properties seem to be numeric.

**Edit**

These two online tools seem to validate the JSON correctly (or at least in line with what Firebase expects):

- http://www.jslint.com/
- http://jsonlint.com/

The second one also pretty prints the JSON, so that might be a reason to prefer one or the other.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I have modified my export SQL accordingly, and the import now works fine.

Comment: Any way I can export my whole SQL database to firebase? I have around 4 tables.

Answer (score 54):

Just in case anyone else comes across this question in the future there is a much easier way of doing this.

You can export your MySQL tables to a CSV file using a tool like SQLYog.

Once you have your CSV file you can then convert that to a JSON format using a free online tool like this one: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

I just imported 40 tables from MySQL to Firebase in about 15 minutes. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: It did help someone! (2 years later) THANK YOU

Comment: Is it secure to upload a CSV contains thousands of sensitive records to 3rd party server?

Comment: Yea iam with Muhammad on this, uploading sensitive data to any server is probably not the best idea.

Comment: You don’t need to use an online converter. Reading data from a CSV file and writing it to JSON is almost a trivial thing to do in many programming languages such as JavaScript, Python or PHP

Comment: You are NOT uploading any data to convertcsv.com - all processing takes place in the browser on YOUR computer.

Answer (score 3):

The Table Data Export wizard supports the data to be exported in JSON format

1. Right click on Table Name and Select Table Data Export Wizard

[image]

2. Select the Column values to be exported and in the following screen there is an option to export data as either csv/ json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with json_object:

`SELECT CONCAT(json_object('id', id, 'word', word, 'wordmeaning', wordmeaning, 'wordlength', wordlength),",")   FROM dictionary;`