# Import into Firebase from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, import, export, firebase

I am trying to import a MongoDB collection into Firebase. I have created an export file in mongo using the command **mongoexport -d RxData -c rxInfos -o rx_export.json**. When i try to import the file into Filebase, i get the error **Error parsing JSON data. Please validate your input.**

I was assuming that because Firebase is bulit on MongoDB that it would just be a simple export --> import process. Is there something that I am missing here?

The export file is available here and is ~ 200 MB.

http://www.filedropper.com/rxexport[1](http://www.filedropper.com/rxexport)

Comment: Does the export.json parse as valid JSON data?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't validate. Its being exported out of an existing MongoDB collection. I would assume that the JSON file created from this would be valid.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922121/209103

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the file `rx_export.json` that you uploaded and linked, there are a few problems:

- The file is not valid JSON as a whole, though each line is valid JSON by itself. If you take a look at the file line-by-line, you'll see the following, which is lacking a surrounding object, keys for each child object, and commas delimiting each child:

  ```
  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "<id1>" }, ... }
  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "<id2>" }, ... }
  ```
- Also, Firebase currently imposes some key restrictions (see https://www.firebase.com/docs/creating-references.html) and the following are not permitted, though some are present in your file:

  - `.` (period)
  - `$` (dollar sign)
  - `[` (left square bracket)
  - `]` (right square bracket)
  - `#` (hash or pound sign)
  - `/` (forward slash)

Comment: That was it. I'm still confused that MongoDB wouldn't wrap the export results with the collection name or something. I added an array wrapper to the json file and removed the $ signs for the oid's and the file imported sucessfully. An updated sample file can be found here.  http://www.filedropper.com/rxsamplejson Thank you for your help.