# How do i sql export table structure and data to firebase?

Tags: sql-server, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on Xamarin Mobile App. I had SQL as my server database. However hosting SQL on Amazon or Microsoft is costing a lot. So I need to move to Firebase. I am very new to firebase.

How do I SQL export table structure and data to firebase?

Comment: This question was more adequately answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916172/migrating-data-into-firebase-from-mysql?newreg=80aa526c8e6e446385ffb5a15b7dc4e6
By chip dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is a NoSQL database. You cannot simply export the data from SQL and import it into Firebase.

I recommend that you read about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watch out [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) video series and then read the [Firebase Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

Comment: Thank you @Frank, your answer is much helpful to make a design decision .. I will look on your links ..

Comment: By the way,  just on curious once the data is stored on firebase .. is it possible to generate report or run select queries as how we have it on SQL to see the back end results. Does firebase has any Studio environment to view the tables or something like that .. i am very new to NoSQL concept ..

Comment: If you want to use a SQL Server approach to using your database, I'd recommend sticking to SQL Server. Switching to another paradigm and looking for the same experience (but cheaper) is going to lead to disappointment. Please study the links I provided, they provide a better introduction than I can give. They'll teach you how different Firebase is from your SQL Server experience.

Comment: I am working on a NON profit project and more over i am a student .. i will not be able to afford the cloud storage unit .. I will have to work on something free hosting .. Google firebase would be better option .. i firmly believe ..

Comment: It can be. But trying to directly start from your SQL Server experience and map it to a NoSQL database such as Firebase is not possible. Again: study the links I provided, which give the best introduction to the topic. After reading/viewing those, you'll be in a much better decision to decide if and how Firebase can be useful for you.

Comment: I will have to rewrite my code work which is currently connected to sql database to firebase .. i will go through the links provided by you to understand the differences ... and will do accordingly..