# Should I use Firebase for my Android APP if I know server coding?

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server

Should I use Firebase ?
I have read about Firebase , it is new to me.
I know Sql and Php for server side coding.I want to create Android App which will provide users to interact with each other , it will contain follow each other, send image and chatting with each other
Should I use HostGator (my hosting) or it is better to use Firebase in this case ?
I am paying $13 per month for hosting

Answer should contain followings:

1)Firebase or Hostgator is better in this case?

2)Why?(explain with details if possible)

3)which one will cost less

4)will I be able to change from one to another (from Hostgator to Firebase and reverse) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Firebase and regular SQL (like Hostgator) aren't the same. Firebase provides a realtime database. That means that if you change the value of an entry, it will be change too on every devices connected. Also, I suppose Hostgator is using a RDBMS (Relation DataBase Management System), in that case, you need to create a structure to stock your data (datatables, columns ...) which you don't need to do in Firebase (and other NoSQL DBMS).

2) There is not an obvious better option. It depends on what you really want. You shoud look at the Firebase documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/. I personnaly used Firebase into one Android project in order to get push notification, and I have to admit this was easy to implement.

3) Firebase provides a free-tier and a $25 one with several options : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/. With RDBMS (Mysql, PostgreSQL, Oracle ...), it depends of the server, you can have one free or a $10.000 one. Both will do the job.

4) With a lot of work, yes you can. As I said in 1), Firebase doesn't need a fixed architecture, while RDBMS needs one. So to import from Firebase to RDBMS, you'll need to fix this 'problem', and before importing, create the tables, columns, foreign keys etc... From RDBMS to Firebase, the hard thing will be the keys that are generated by Firebase. I never did that, so I can't tell, but seems quite easy : [Migrating data into Firebase from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916172/migrating-data-into-firebase-from-mysql) The biggest problem will be changing your entire application if you want to change from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

all your questions depends on what type and how much users your application can reach,`Firebase` and `Hostgator` are not the same you can't compare between them. Using `Firebase` makes you win more time and effort to develop your own API and host it at `Hostgator` and developing upload and download scripts using PHP, but it can cost you more if you are reaching a big number of users. Exporting database from `Firebase` will be in `JSON` format to upload it into `MySql` or relation database will be a little hard work and few PHP lines of code.